# Is there a way to prevent the box-shadow cumulative effect from overlapping elements?

Tags: html, css

If 2 elements overlap and both have the same `box-shadow` applied, the shadow is cumulative at the point where the elements intersect. Is there a way to make the shadow look the same even if elements overlap?

The example below shows what I mean. I've tried the various options with `mix-blend-mode` to no avail.

```css
.div1,.div2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 1px gray;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
}

.div2 {
   top: 25px;
   background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```

Comment: My first question is: why not remove the box-shadow from one of the `divs`? If that's not possible, can you apply `overflow: hidden` to one of them?

Comment: @shainanigans The 2 divs are independent so I don't believe overflow would help here. I've formatted them differently in the example, but I would like them to look like one single element in my application (the overlap is caused by scrolling) and the shadow stands out

Comment: Do you mean that on page load the two elements do not overlap, but as the users scroll, they do?

Comment: @shainanigans yes, that is correct

Answer (score 1):

Use a `drop-shadow` on a parent element. I am using the body here but you have to consider another element based on your real code

```css
.div1,.div2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
}

.div2 {
   top: 25px;
   background-color: green;
}

body {
  filter:drop-shadow(1px 1px 5px gray)
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```